# statements are appearing as undefined JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

So, I was checking my code over on JSLint and I got it down to two errors that I have no clue on how to fix the errors.

Here is the Code.

```
function DeviceEnter() { 'use strict'; var Device = prompt("Please enter your Device, i.e iPhone 4s, 8.1.3", "iPhone 4s 8.1.3");  localStorage.setItem("Device", Device); }
```

The errors are:

1. 'prompt' was used before it was defined.
2. 'localStorage' was used before it was defined.

I searched around and could not find an answer to the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: you can "assume a browser" if that's where the code will be run.

Comment: Thanks I clicked the option and it got rid of one of the errors for some reason, "'prompt' was used before it was defined." still is an error.

Comment: you can also allow mis-ordered definitions. it might be dogma related to the use of `prompt()` i wouldn't worry about it, there's nothing wrong with ignoring lint errors as long as you know what you're ignoring.

Comment: The code worked. So I think I should leave it alone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the 'Assume a browser' option to true, and use `window.prompt` and `window.localStorage`. JavaScript can be used in environments outside of browser windows, so JSLint makes no assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

[JSLint has a `browser` option](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#browser) to tell the linter that you're linting the code with a browser environment in mind. This will tell the linter that these are expected to be defined and it should not warn when these globals are found (`alert`, `prompt`, etc.)

Comment: I turned on the browser option, and it only fixed on of the errors. " 'prompt' was used before it was defined." is the only when left.